# How to create crossplatform tabbar without using plugins?

Tags: cordova, tabbar

I am using phonegap to develop crossplatform apps. Is there any method to create tabbar like native iOS app without using plugins? If not, how should I develop for cross platform?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at KendoUI (http://kendoui.com). It's not free (mobile I think it ~$200 per developer) but it does a pretty nice cross platform html/css/js tabbar in iOS and Android and BlackBerry.

Comment: Thank you so much, Devgeeks. My company not support me to use a not free library. I need to find another way to fix this problem.

Comment: Ah, then your only hope is to do it yourself using CSS/JS.